# What gives more exp?

Tags: succubox

Is it faster leveling to have employees assigned to buying and opening lootboxes or have the employees grind the game for levels?

Considering the game is making fun of lootbox industry, I would guess that's the fastest way, but I'm looking for an answer based on facts or calculations.

Comment: By playing around with the %ages in grinding and buying/opening lootboxes, it seems that lootboxes are superior to grinding, but other than "it seems like it", I don't have any evidence that one is faster than the other.

Comment: OVERKILL bonus is big, so if you have a lot of employees, assign them to grinding all at once and you'll have massive, but quickly diminishing returns as enemies get more powerful. Loot boxes income is more steady.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can report that I had 99% of my workforce dedicated to grinding, and was stalled out at around level 30.  Then I switched to 50% buy/50% open loot boxes, and immediately went up three levels.  Haven't looked at the source code, but it seems clear that the loot boxes are the way to go, at least at higher levels.

Comment: This pretty much goes with what I have observed and I doubt I'll get a better answer, so I will accept this.